# Building a Docker image with deprecated dependencies

Tags: php, apache, docker, debian, mcrypt

I am struggling to build a Docker image with Debian Wheezy, Apache 2.2, PHP 5 with mcrypt enabled. I want to use it to do some maintenance on a quirky, legacy prestashop application.

Most semi-automatic procedures include Apache 2.4 and that will not work. I would have thought that by now there would be an online tool to auto-generate Docker images to specifications.

How should I do it? Should I use Docker compose?

Comment: In a sense, Dockerfile **is** the tool you're talking about - it allows one to specify exactly what's installed/configured inside your image.  (Though I accept that often the install procedure for things is non-trivial!)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your specific problem. When building an image with `debian:wheezy` as a base image, you can easily set up Apache 2.2 and PHP 5 directly from Wheezy's official repositories.

Comment: You are correct thanks. I think I almost figured it out. Just need to find a way to start mysql and apache on image run.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far. I am only missing how to start mysql and apache on image run.

```
FROM debian:wheezy

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    subversion ssl-cert nano wget unzip && \
    echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list && \
    wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg -O- | apt-key add - && \
    echo mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password yourpass | debconf-set-selections && \
    echo mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password yourpass | debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    apache2 apache2-doc apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 \
    openssl php-pear php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-memcache php5-readline \
    subversion ssl-cert nano wget unzip \
    mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common && \
    /etc/init.d/mysql start && \
    mysql -u root -pyourpass -e "create database mydb;" && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default && \
    mkdir -p /var/www/html && \
    chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/

COPY conf/etc/ /etc/
COPY mydump.sql /var/www/html/mydump.sql

RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start && \
    mysql -u root -pyourpass -h localhost mydb < /var/www/html/mydump.sql && \
    rm /var/www/html/mydump.sql

VOLUME ["/var/www", "/var/log/apache2", "/etc/apache2", "/var/lib/mysql"]

EXPOSE 80 443 3306
```